# _.each will not loop through localStorage?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

When I try and run

```
_.each(localStorage, function(val){console.log(val)});
```

I get undefined for each value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly iterate through `LocalStorage` because it's a [Storage object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Storage).

If you want all the items in LocalStorage as an array, you can use [`_.values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values):

```
var values = _.values(localStorage);
```

Then you can iterate through the values:

```
_.each(values, function (val) { console.log(val); });
```

Comment: Underscore's each loop can loop through objects (to my knowledge)

Comment: Objects but not Storage objects.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need underscore.js

```
for(var key in localStorage) { 
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(key))
}
```

or encapsulated

```
Object.keys(localStorage).map(function(key) { 
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(key)) 
})
```